# A problem where I'm finding the largest number you can "make" out of several numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Sample input:

```
4
123 124 56 90
```

I'm to find the largest possible number you can get by combining each of these numbers together in whatever possible way.

So, the possible combinations for those numbers are {1231245690, 1241235690, 5612312490, 9012312456, 9056124123, etc.}, with the largest number being 9056124123.

I'm thinking of this problem like this: The largest number would start with the largest last digit in the set. So, the largest number here would start with "9", therefore 90 is the first number I'm concerned with. Then, I'm looking at the rest of the set with the largest last digit, which would be "5", so 56 is the second number I'm concerned with. If the largest last digit is a tie, I'd evaluate the second to last digit, etc.

For one, let me know if I'm the right track here with how I'm thinking about the problem, and if I am, which structures/types should I be looking at in order to implement this? Would this require something to do with bit manipulation? Because I'm a little stuck on that part.

Comment: I think what you meant is the largest **first** digit , example if the numbers are ```123 124 56 90``` you should start at ```90``` since it has the largest **first** digit which is ```9```.

Comment: Sort them considering them as strings in descending order. And then concat.

Comment: @SunilBN That doesn't work.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Can you give one counter example? I am not able to come up with one.

Comment: @SunilBN `{80, 807}`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem more clearly, in case (for some reason) they define `xy` > `xyz`, `{504, 50, 506}`. This fails in both cases.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I changed sort comparator. That will do the trick. check answer below

Comment: I haven't had the chance to look at the responses yet. Please give me a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost on right path. There is no need for bit manipulation.
Sorting them using custom String comparator function as below is enough.

```
Collections.sort(inputArray, new Comparator < String > () {
 public int compare(String a, String b) {
  //if a = "80", b = "807"
  String ab = a + b; // 80807
  String ba = b + a; //80780
  // now compare
  return ab.compareTo(ba) > 0 ? -1 : 1;
 }
});
```

later concat them.

[@Dawood ibn Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/dawood-ibn-kareem) Thanks for pointing out the edge case.

Comment: This saves the reader's brain because it's so direct. Just to point out, you could have simply multiplied by `-1` or do the `compareTo` in the reverse direction.

Comment: Just sorting isn't enough. We will also need to remove the leading zeroes in the final result. Example of such a case: `[0,0]`

Comment: Why are you upvoting this answer? It doesn't answer the OP's question since the OP is just asking if he/she is on the right path. The OP did not ask for the solution.

Comment: @Mark I have not written the complete solution. I have mentioned what is the custom sort to be used with an example.

Comment: This is almost everything they need to know.

Answer (score 3):

Carefully examine where the numbers are placed in your sample output. 90 56 124 123 The numbers go from greatest to least, depending on what the biggest **digit** is from the left. (Biggest first digit - @Mark)

There are possible inputs which require tiebreaking.
Given the numbers '80, 807, and 000'

Compare them from left to right.

```
8 0
| |\
8 0 7
```

Because 807 is longer than 80, compare the last bit of 807 (7) to 80.

```
7
|
8 0
```

Comparison completed, because the 8 of 80 was compared to the 7 of 807, showing that 80 should be first. Put 80 and 807 together and get 80807, and of course add the 000.

Comment: Have I revealed too much? Be honest.

Comment: I'd doubt it. The OP still needs to code the algorithm, and cover any edge cases.

Comment: I don't believe this is actually correct.  I'm sure if you turn this idea into code, I'll be able to find a test case on which it fails.

Comment: It might be unclearly explained. For example, if I inputted the numbers 199, 911, and 500, this method would compare the numbers by the first digit and get 911500199, the biggest number.

Comment: OK, try `{80, 809}`.  Then try `{80, 807}`.  How will your sort order work for each of those two cases?

Comment: Adjustments will be needed. In a tiebreak (when they have the same first digit and different lengths), many things will have to be decided.

Comment: Given the numbers '80, 807, and 000', take the first digit of the longer number, that isn't part of the first section of the smaller number; like the 80 in 807 isn't eligible for use because it's the prefix of 80. Compare this "last (chunk)" of the longer number to other numbers to decide if the shorter or longer number should go first.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  But have a go at turning it into code.  I will upvote if you get it right.

Comment: It is rather unclear and hard to explain. I can translate badly explained questions from this website most of the time, but with this answer I am nowhere near to explaining it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189498/discussion-between-failingcoder-and-dawood-ibn-kareem).

Answer (score 1):

You are on a good path!

The easiest to go about types is to turn the numbers into strings. That allows you to quickly access the first, second,... digit of the original numbers. And concatenation is also much easier to do for strings!

Answer (score 1):

Convert the numbers to strings, pad them with "X" on the right to make them all the same length, sort descending, concatenate removing the "X"s, there is your result.

Comment: This doesn't always work.  Consider the strings `{80, 809}`.  Your algorithm returns 80809, but the correct answer is 80980.

Comment: You are right. You have to use a character that comes before the digits when sorting, for example "." But since this looks like homework, I tried not to give too much away and that's where I failed.

Comment: That also doesn't work.  Consider the strings `{80, 807}`.  Your new algorithm returns 80780, but the correct answer is 80807.